# async await break the sequence node.js

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I am newbie on async await approach. I built the function where async await approach is used. But somehow my sequence is break through forEach Loop

```
const newUser = async () => {
  try {
    let t1Data = await Users.find({ sequenceid: 1 });
    if (t1Data.length > 0) {
      let newData = t1Data[0].messagescore;
      console.log("A");
      newData.forEach(async (x, i) => {
        let updateColumn = await Users.update(
          { sequenceid: 1 },
          {
            $push: {
              messagescorebefore: {
                userid: x.userid,
                score: parseFloat(x.score.toFixed(2))
              }
            }
          }
        );
        console.log(i + " Updated");
        return updateColumn;
      });
      console.log("B");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

newUser();

By this console sequence will be like this
-> A
-> B
-> 0 Updated
-> 1 Updated
```

Now Desired result will be like this which I did not get:

```
-> A
-> 0 Updated
-> 1 Updated
-> B
```

May be I am doing something wrong on forEach Loop.

Guys if you know where I am wrong then please let me know. Any help is really Appreciated.

/********** Updated Logic as suggestion But still got one issue *************/

```
const newUser = async () => {
  try {
    let t1Data = await Users.find({ sequenceid: 1 });
    if (t1Data.length > 0) {
      let newData = t1Data[0].messagescore;
      console.log("A");
      await Promise.all(
        newData.map( async (x, i) => {
          let updateColumn = await Users.update(
           { sequenceid: 1 },
           {
             $push: {
               messagescorebefore: {
                 userid: x.userid,
                 score: parseFloat(x.score.toFixed(2))
               }
             }
           }
         );
        console.log(i + " Updated");
        return updateColumn
        })
      )
        console.log(i + " Updated");
        return updateColumn;
      });
      console.log("B");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

newUser();
```

In this Logic Some Times my Loop breaks under map Function. Rest all things work fine.

Under map Function I console (i), so some times it breaks the sequence..

Can anyone guide me where I am wrong.....

Comment: Async should be used for a function which works asynchronously and returns a Promise. Await is needed to wait that function until the value is returned.

Comment: Regarding your update: you didn't `await` the promise returned by `Promise.all(…)`

Comment: Dear I forgot to write the await before Promise.all. Here I forgot to write the await. Still My issues is same

Answer (score 0):

Replace `forEach` loop with a `for` loop. async/await does not work in a forEach loop. 
See it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop).

If you want a declarative style use [bluebird Promise.each](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html)

Comment: Thanks Sagar Karira. Now I got the desired result

Comment: Great, please mark this as a verified answer. Thanks.

Comment: Dear I updated the question. Now I have one issue under map function. Loop Sequence break under map function.